# to_csv pandas python not show tabluar format in excel

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file, export

I want to export my file as CSV file. but when I open the CSV file with excel the appearance doesn't show as columnar view and show as a one string and all filelds concat together.
what is the problem: the picture is my goal.(Tabular format)
[image]

this is my code:
first I export the result from my database:

```
 import cx_Oracle
    query = """select * from test"""
    db = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str,encoding="UTF-8")
    curs = db.cursor()
    curs.execute(query)
    result = curs.fetchall()
```

then I exort file in local os and the via ftp I upload in destination folder in another server:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime,timedelta
    import ftplib
    df = pd.DataFrame(result)
    df = df.rename_axis(None)
    df.to_csv('C:\\test\\test.csv',index=False,header=False, 
encoding='utf-16',sep = ',')
    today = str(datetime.now() - timedelta(1))[:10]
    today = today.split('-')
    final_today = today[1]+today[2]
    outputName = 'test%s.csv'%final_today
    session = ftplib.FTP('1.1.1.1','test', 'test')
    Output_Directory = '/test'
    session.cwd(Output_Directory)
    fh = open('C:\\tets\\test.csv','rb')
    session.storbinary('STOR '+ outputName, fh)     # send the file
    fh.close()                                    # close file and FTP
    session.quit()
```

Comment: Could you please share the code that you are using without which we would not be able to figure out what is wrong with your code?

Comment: There's a delimitter setting where you need specify "," for getting tabular format. Check your settings while opening file in excel

Answer (score 0):

the problem solved by considering **sep = '\t'** in to_csv function.